# R's AzureKusto library and access to Azure Log Analytics

Tags: r, azure-log-analytics, azure-data-explorer

I am wondering how to get the data from Azure Log Analytics with AzureKusto library for R.
The `server` parameter reads:

> `server`: The URI of the server, usually of the form
>   'https://clustername.location.kusto.windows.net'. addr, address,
>   network address, datasource, host

I have no idea where to find this information.

Thanks in advance : )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the SDK you're looking at has been written to query Kusto/ADX clusters, and not Azure Log Analytics resources.

that said, you could potentially still use it, and [Query data in Azure Monitor using Azure Data Explorer (Preview)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/query-monitor-data)

Comment: Thanks, @Yoni. I will ask the engineers if this is what they can do for me. Out of curiosity - would it be possible to query LA directly? I believe this is what Excel does.

Comment: Log Analytics has a REST API: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/loganalytics/query